# numpy count elements across axis 0 matching values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Given a 3D array such as:

```
array = np.random.randint(1, 6, (3, 3, 3))
```

and an array of maximum values across axis 0:

```
max_array = array.max(axis=0)
```

Is there a vectorised way to count the number of elements in axis 0 of array which are equal to the value of the matching index in max_array? For example, if array contains [1, 3, 3] in one axis 0 position, the output is 2, and so on for the other 8 positions, returning an array with the counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the number of values in `x` which equal the corresponding value in `xmax`, you could use:

```
(x == xmax).sum(axis=0)
```

Note that since `x` has shape (3,3,3) and `xmax` has shape (3,3), the expression `x == xmax` causes NumPy to [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) `xmax` up to shape (3,3,3) where the new axis is added on the left.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)
x = np.random.randint(1, 6, (3,3,3))
print(x)
# [[[3 5 5]
#   [3 2 1]
#   [3 4 1]]

#  [[1 5 4]
#   [1 4 1]
#   [2 3 4]]

#  [[2 3 3]
#   [2 1 1]
#   [5 1 2]]]

xmax = x.max(axis=0)
print(xmax)
# [[3 5 5]
#  [3 4 1]
#  [5 4 4]]

count = (x == xmax).sum(axis=0)
print(count)
# [[1 2 1]
#  [1 1 3]
#  [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: Brilliant! I never came across a simple solution like x == xmax, but this exactly what I need, thank you.